# How to use Yii2 debugger when developing RESTful application?

Tags: rest, debugging, yii2, profiler

Like in the guide, I have created RESTful controller UserController.

```
namespace app\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class UserController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\User';
}
```

And when I make request `GET /users`, it works.

But I have no idea what queries does Yii2 execute behind the scene, and I do not know how long do they last.

Can I somehow use Yii2 debugger to debug and profile queries ? If not, what is the alternative for this ?

Comment: Refer this [issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7471)

Comment: I don't see these options: Select API request from previous requests dropdown. Also, what web page I should open ? My api request is targeting Controller that returns JSON it does not generate web page with debugger/html on. It just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: also try this: https://github.com/zhuravljov/yii2-rest. I didn't try yet it but as it uses a web interface then I guess the debugger should record all the requests if session is enabled.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**To see requests in Debugger for APIs**

1. Add this in you API config file  -

   ```
   $config = [
       'id' => 'app-api',
       'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),    
       'bootstrap' => ['log'],
       ......
       ....
   ]
   if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
       // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
       $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
       $config['modules']['debug'] = [
           'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
           'allowedIPs' => ['your_ip_address'], // accessible to this ip address only
       ];

       $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
       $config['modules']['gii'] = [
           'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
       ];
   }

   return $config;
   ```
2. In web/index.php of API folder -

   ```
   defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
   defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
   ```
3. Access debugger by below URL-

   ```
   http://localhost/yii2-app/api/web/debug/default/view
   ```

**To change API's default actions like - create,update,view,index,delete
 write below code in controller**

```
/* Declare actions supported by APIs (Added in api/modules/v1/components/controller.php too) */
    public function actions(){
        $actions = parent::actions();
        unset($actions['create']);
        unset($actions['update']);
        unset($actions['delete']);
        unset($actions['view']);
        unset($actions['index']);
        return $actions;
    }

    /* Declare methods supported by APIs */
    protected function verbs(){
        return [
            'create' => ['POST'],
            'update' => ['PUT', 'PATCH','POST'],
            'delete' => ['DELETE'],
            'view' => ['GET'],
            'index'=>['GET'],
        ];
    }
    public function actionCreate(){echo "in create action";die;}
```

Comment: This is basically all that I needed to do, but didn't knew that I can: `localhost/api/debug/default/view` . My API is stand-alone application, and I had no idea that I can access debugger like this. Thanks man !

Comment: Your welcome! but make sure you add your IP address in allowedIPs array (Answer updated) else anyone can access this log.